# grep non matching port@server

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I want a regexp for below input

```
echo "1280@lic1 1728@lic1 1280@lic2.local 1924@lic1"| grep -Po 'regexp'
```

I want output as words not containing 1280 as below

```
1728@lic1 1924@lic1
```

Comment: you question is not clear. please explain it more properly

Comment: Do you want to split a word by space and then return each word which doesn't contain 1280?

Comment: `perl -E '@a=split /\s+/,q{1280@lic1 1728@lic1 1280@lic2.local 1924@lic1}; say for grep !/1280/,@a'`

Comment: @AbhiNickz No need to split, just grep words that doesn't contain 1280

Comment: I want you to write your own code.

Comment: @stevieb It's giving desired ouput, but can it be done with grep. As string will be in stored in one variable, so I want to echo and grep it

Comment: yes, but you had perl tag, and I'm a perl person. I did use perl's grep(), but I guess that didn't count ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead and lookbehind regex:

```
echo "1280@lic1 1728@lic1 1280@lic2.local 1924@lic1"| grep -Po '(?<=\s|^)(?!\S*1280)\S+'

1728@lic1
1924@lic1
```

- `(?<=\s|^)` asserts there a whitespace or line start before our match
- `(?!\S*1280)` asserts that there is no `1280` in the word

Pipe the result to `tr '\n' ' '` if you want to remove newlines from this output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "1280@lic1 1728@lic1 1280@lic2.local 1924@lic1" | sed 's/1280@[.a-z0-9]*//g'
 1728@lic1  1924@lic1
```

The `sed` command will delete all occurrences of the strings that you don't want.

You can't do this with `grep` directly as `grep` works line by line.  The `-o` flag to `grep` *will* allow you to get each matched word back, but the `-v` flag (to negate the match) works only on the whole line.  You would have to ask `grep` for all matches that you would like to see if you wanted to do it that way (unless you "cheat" with Perl regular expressions, which is a GNU extension to `grep`).

Alternatively, you could break down the output for `grep` inte several lines and do it this way instead:

```
$ echo "1280@lic1 1728@lic1 1280@lic2.local 1924@lic1" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v '1280'
1728@lic1
1924@lic1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` and `grep` and get your desired output.

code

```
echo "1280@lic1 1728@lic1 1280@lic2.local 1924@lic1"| sed 's/1280@[0-9,a-z,A-Z,.]\+//g' | grep -Po '\d+@[A-Z,a-z,0-9,\.]+'
```

Hope this will work for you.